# Use of tmpfs on embedded Linux systems

Tags: linux, filesystems

I am going to bring up a new embedded Linux system soon, kernel version 3.2.  The main root filesystem needs to be writable as we do software image updates, and we do want to keep the logs under /var/log persisted for analysis after reboots.

One technique I've seen used is to mount /tmp as tmpfs which makes sense, as we don't need anything in /tmp to be maintained across reboots.  What other directories in a Linux system will undergo a lot of writes, but do not need to be maintained across reboots?  I've seen so far:

```
/tmp
/var/run
```

can anyone suggest any other candidates for tmpfs?

Comment: Well, I can think of `/var/tmp`, kind of.

Comment: Good, I'll add it to my list

Comment: Actually, I was just reading the FHS standard at http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.pdf, it says that /var/tmp is for "Temporary files preserved between system reboots", so I'd better keep that on the flash memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

```
/tmp
/var/run
```

And

```
/var/tmp
```

too. Yes, `/var/tmp` is suppose to preserve temporary files between system reboots, but practically, my `/var/tmp/` is always empty. It won't hurt to put that in tmpfs -- I've been doing that for more than 10 years and so far so good.

Also, I always put `/run/lock` in tmpfs and so far so good as well. If you have `udev` then it will put `/dev` on `devtmpfs`. Also my system, automatically put `/run` and `/run/shm` in tmpfs. Depending on your system, you may consider doing that as well.

HTH